# Mac laptop screen damaged, can't see anything.

Tags: mac, laptop, external-display

Hooked up external monitor but display not mirrored . F5 nor F8 work to get mirrored display?
Given the mac laptop screen damaged, can't see anything o its screen

Answer (score 0):

Press Command-F1 to toggle between video mirroring and extended desktop.

Press Command-F2 to detect displays.